# Android equivalent to Java's Swing JSpinner

Tags: android

I want to use a control similar to Swing JSpinner in an Android application. I know that Android has a widget called Spinner, but it's more like a combo box than a JSpinner. I've noticed that DatePicker and TimePicker widgets are using components that are just like JSpinner. The only problem is that I don't really want Date or Time. I just want to get some integer, say from 1 to 50, that user chooses. Is this possible? I've searched Android API reference in and out, but I couldn't find any clue on how to do this. Any help or hint would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Tomislav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the functionality for the TimePicker is provided by a hidden internal class named NumberPicker, which would probably be exactly what you wanted if only the folks at Google had made it available.

You might want to go to [the android source code](http://android.git.kernel.org/) and lookup the source to [android.widget.NumberPicker](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=core/java/android/widget/NumberPicker.java;hb=HEAD) in the frameworks/base repository.  (The repository treats it as if it were a publicly available class, though I see no sign of it in the released dev jars.)

Comment: Thanks, beekeper. I was refusing to believe that Google chose to hide that class. I thought I wasn't reading the docs thoroughly enough. Now that you provided me with the name of the class, I found someone already extracted it from source, along with appropriate drawables and layouts for usage in a preferences. So here it is: http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5

Answer (score 1):

I stole the spinner from Astrid, which stole it from Android's source.

Take a gander here:

http://github.com/ralphleon/TeaTimer/tree/master/src/goo/TeaTimer/widget/

Though my app is GPL, the number picker code is under the permissive Apache license!